# AngularJs with librairy angular-feeds

Tags: angularjs, rss

I 'm a new in Angularjs and I use library angular-feeds  see https://github.com/siddii/angular-feeds to parse rss file.

I look scripts of library I don't really  understand the code . It is possible to add element to feed ( an other that title , content  or contentSnippet )?

In fact , In my rss file I have a   tag witch contains an image and I want to extract it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the post-render JavaScript function to modify the feed. For example, this adds target attributes to feed's links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('my-feeds', [ 'feeds' ]);

    function feedPostRender(element) {
      $(element).find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
    }
</script>


<feed summary="true" url="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=angularjs&sort=newest" count="5" post-render="feedPostRender" />
```